# Cassandra datastax java driver ,can not connect to server "No handler set for stream"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

[image]

If I create a new project like this .

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
```

this code works.

But if I take all the jars from this project and migrate the jars to my own project .the code above doesn't work and it says:

```
13/07/01 16:27:16 ERROR core.Connection: [/127.0.0.1-1] No handler set for stream 1 (this is a bug, either of this driver or of Cassandra, you should report it)
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: [/127.0.0.1])
```

Comment: but my own project is not a "maven project" when created

Comment: oh , there exist a way to "enable dependency management"

Comment: The message clearly states "this is a bug, either of this driver or of Cassandra"

Answer (score 1):

What version of Cassandra are you running?  Have you enabled the native protocol in your cassandra.yaml?

In Cassandra 1.2.0-1.2.4 the native protocol was disabled by default, but in 1.2.5+ it's on by default.

See https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.2.5/conf/cassandra.yaml#L335

That's the most common reason I've seen for not being able to connect with the driver.

Comment: Thank you .It is not the problem of the server-site.I have solve it by add the using the maven way